# DWM1000 getting X position

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded

I am currently working on code for use with DWM1000 modules I am using two anchors and one tag I recieve the distance between both anchors to the tag and trying to get the x,y position of the tag. But my x coords for the tag isn't right and seems to be acting like y coord as it changes when i move the tag closer to the anchors I was hoping someone could look at my code and see what I am doing wrong.

```
float a_r = (pow(-dist_right,2) + pow(dist_left,2) - pow(dist_l_r,2)) / (-2*dist_l_r);
      x = dist_l_r/2 - a_r;
      float t = pow(dist_right,2) - pow(a_r,2);
      if(dist_left < dist_right){
        Serial.println("Left");;
      }else{
        Serial.println("Right");
      }

      Serial.print("Distance Right: ");Serial.println(dist_right);
      Serial.print("Distance Left: ");Serial.println(dist_left);
      diff = abs(dist_left - dist_right);
      Serial.print("Difference: ");Serial.println(diff);
      Serial.print("A_R: ");Serial.println(a_r);
      Serial.print("T: ");Serial.println(t);
      Serial.print("X: ");Serial.println(x);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two reference point *[trilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_range_multilateration)* yields two solutions - the actual location and a false location.  In the case where the reference points form a base line along some impassable barrier such as a wall, then the ambiguity is resolvable by this additional information.

Given:

[image]

Attribution: By NavigationGuy - Own work, CC BY-SA 4.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=75898777

Then

[image]

Thus the code:

```
x = ((dist_left * dist_left) - (dist_right * dist-right) + (dist_l_r * dist_l_r)) /
    (2 * dist_l_r) ;

y = sqrt((dist_left * dist_left) - (x * x)) ;
```

In your code your `a_r` variable corresponds to `x` above (my frame of reference is rotated by 90 degrees with respect to yours, but is arbitrary in any case), but your `x` variable bares no resemblance to `y` above.  Your `x` variable is proportional to `a_r` not orthogonal to it, so it is not at all surprising that it varies depending on `a_r`.

To maintain your frame of reference and variable naming then:

```
x = sqrt((dist_left * dist_left) - (a_r * a_r)) ;
```

of if you prefer:

```
x = sqrt(pow(dist_left,2) - pow(a_r, 2)) ;
```